# DES algorithm java code using string as input

Tags: java, algorithm, des

I am in search of Java implementation of the DES algorithm where I want a string as input. Can anybody guide me where to find it?

Comment: `String.getBytes()` is probably what you want instead.

Comment: I'm a complete newbie in Java too :(. Could you link me to a working Java code where I can use the above method U just mentioned?

Comment: You can also look at this http://www.mkyong.com/java/jce-encryption-data-encryption-standard-des-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @m0skit0 pointed out, you need `inputString.getBytes()`, here is a sample code link also http://java-espresso.blogspot.com/2011/09/des-algorithm-code-in-java.html

Comment: Done.. Didn't know about that.. New here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq